# Cut a longer word/string in smaller chunks for fitting a field

Tags: c#, string, word-wrap

I want to fill a field with a string of many words. When I have huge words I need a to split the word. If my word is longer than 10 letters I need a space at position 5 of this word.

How do I get the new "myString" with shorter words?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myString = "This is my string with some loooooooooooooong words. Please devide meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
        var myStringSplit = myString.Split();
        var query = myStringSplit.Where(x => x.Length > 10).ToList();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            item.Insert(5, " ");
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** My expected result: `myString = "This is my strin g with some loooo ooooo ooooo ng words. Pleas e devid e meeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee e"`;

Comment: So then what's your question?

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: You are showing us your code...what about it is not working?  Why did you show us your code?

Comment: Still unclear what you want to do... For example in the string given, what result you want?

Comment: @kame please add what you expect to get as a result. It's not clear from your question what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example how you can get your result:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myString = "This is my string with some loooooooooooooong words. Please devide meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
    string[] myStringSplit = myString.Split();
    for (int i =0;i<myStringSplit.Length;i++)
    {
        if(myStringSplit[i].Length>5)
            myStringSplit[i] = Regex.Replace(myStringSplit[i], ".{5}(?=.)", "$0 ");
    }
    var resultString = myStringSplit.Aggregate((x,y)=> x+" "+y);
    Console.WriteLine(resultString);
}
```

The output will be the following:

> This is my strin g with some loooo ooooo ooooo ng words . Pleas e
>   devid e meeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee e

Comment: The `Regex` should be `Regex.Replace(myStringSplit[i], ".{5}(?=.)", "$0 ");` or `".{5}(?!$)"` (test with a string of 10 characters, with your regex it is `12345 67890 ` with an extra space at the end. And instead of `Aggregate` you could use `string.Join`: `string.Join(" ", myStringSplit)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be helpful

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myString = "This is my string with some loooooooooooooong words. Please devide meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
            var myStringSplit = myString.Split();
            var query = myStringSplit.Where(x => x.Length > 10).ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                string outString = Regex.Replace(item, ".{5}", "$0 ");
            }
        }
```

This will separates the string after each five words..

**Edited**

Comment: But I just want to split words with a size longer than 10 characters.

Comment: Edited as per your requirement

Comment: I just want to split the word which is longer than 10 characters. Therefore I have to take the long words first.

Comment: Variable query will holds the values which are longer than the 10 character. Then we are looping the same and adding space after 5 character.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myString = "This is my string with some loooooooooooooong words. Please devide meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
    var newString = string.Empty;
    var myStringSplit = myString.Split();
    var query = myStringSplit.Where(x => x.Length > 10).ToList();
    foreach (var item in myStringSplit)
    {
        if(item.Length > 10)
        {
            var itemToSplit = item;
            itemToSplit.Insert(5, " ");
            newString += itemToSplit;
        }
        else
        {
           newString += item;
        }
    }
}
```

It should be something like this. The reason your attempt is not working is because you are not allowed to edit the item in the foreach loop. [More info on the foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676974/changing-objects-value-in-foreach-loop)